# Where is the source of the media volume control overlay image?

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image]

How can I find the location of the images in the media volume control overlay?

Comment: Spotify image? Usually is an icon stored in the app itself, not easily accessible.

Comment: @Moab no not necessarily spotify. Could be any service using the overlay. I would've thought that windows is storing/caching it somewhere.

Comment: Usually not cached anywhere that I know of, its pulled from the application itself.

Comment: @Moab So you don't think there is anyway of getting this image without pulling it from each service myself?

Comment: There might be, but never looked into how. Maybe someone here will have the answer. Great question.

Comment: If you're talking about the buttons, it could be a custom font or an SVG to support High DPI. So it could be not an image (bitmap) at all. Album Art and app icon are provided by the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I stumbled across the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037406/7274182)

[Here's the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.control.globalsystemmediatransportcontrolssession?view=winrt-19041)

And here's how to how to save the image to the current directory in python

```py
import asyncio
from winrt.windows.media.control import \
    GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager as MediaManager
from winrt.windows.storage.streams import \
    DataReader, Buffer, InputStreamOptions

async def get_media_info():
    sessions = await MediaManager.request_async()

    # This source_app_user_model_id check and if statement is optional
    # Use it if you want to only get a certain player/program's media
    # (e.g. only chrome.exe's media not any other program's).

    current_session = sessions.get_current_session()
    if current_session:  # there needs to be a media session running
        info = await current_session.try_get_media_properties_async()

        # song_attr[0] != '_' ignores system attributes
        info_dict = {song_attr: info.__getattribute__(song_attr) for song_attr in dir(info) if song_attr[0] != '_'}

        # converts winrt vector to list
        info_dict['genres'] = list(info_dict['genres'])

        return info_dict

    # It could be possible to select a program from a list of current
    # available ones. I just haven't implemented this here for my use case.
    # See references for more information.
    raise Exception('No current media session')

current_media_info = asyncio.run(get_media_info())

async def read_stream_into_buffer(stream_ref, buffer):
    readable_stream = await stream_ref.open_read_async()
    readable_stream.read_async(buffer, buffer.capacity, InputStreamOptions.READ_AHEAD)

# create the current_media_info dict with the earlier code first
thumb_stream_ref = current_media_info['thumbnail']

# 5MB (5 million byte) buffer - thumbnail unlikely to be larger
thumb_read_buffer = Buffer(5000000)

# copies data from data stream reference into buffer created above
asyncio.run(read_stream_into_buffer(thumb_stream_ref, thumb_read_buffer))

# reads data (as bytes) from buffer
buffer_reader = DataReader.from_buffer(thumb_read_buffer)
byte_buffer = buffer_reader.read_bytes(thumb_read_buffer.length)

with open('media_thumb.jpg', 'wb+') as fobj:
    fobj.write(bytearray(byte_buffer))
```